# Custom shipping module

Tags: shipping, magento-1, ce-1.9.2.0

I have created a custom shipping module and have defined `collectRates()` and other functions in the module.

I also have onepage checkout enabled. In that page this new shipping module is not getting called. The shipping amount is coming blank.

What do I have to do to get my checkout page and my cart page to automatically call this module to show the right shipping price?

I am using Magento 1.9.2

My carrier class is:

```
<?php

// app/code/local/Envato/Customshippingmethod/Model
class Shopez_Customshippingmethod_Model_Demo
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected $_code = 'shopez_customshippingmethod';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $result->append($this->_getDefaultRate());
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array(
            'shopez_standard' => 'Delivery Based on Cart Subtotal',
        );
    }

    protected function _getDefaultRate()
    {
        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethod($this->_code);
        $rate->setMethodTitle('Delivery Based on Cart Subtotal');
        $rate->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $rate->setCost(0);
        return $rate;
    }

    protected function _getStandardRate()
    {
        /** @var Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Method $rate */
        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethod('large');
        $rate->setMethodTitle('Delivery Based on Cart Subtotal');
        $rate->setPrice(1.23);
        $rate->setCost(0);
        return $rate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider your magento version

Comment: Can you paste your Carrier class?

Answer (score 0):

Your Carrier Class should be as below:

**app/code/local/Namespace/Customshippingmethod/Model**

```
<?php

// app/code/local/Namespace/Customshippingmethod/Model
class namespace_Customshippingmethod_Model_Demo
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
    protected $_code = 'namespace_customshippingmethod';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        $result->append($this->_getDefaultRate());

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array(
            'namespace_customshippingmethod' => $this->getConfigData('name'),
        );
    }

    protected function _getDefaultRate()
    {
        $rate = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $rate->setMethod($this->_code);
        $rate->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $rate->setPrice($this->getConfigData('price'));
        $rate->setCost(0);

        return $rate;
    }
}
```